# How to use template for implementing STACK using LINKEDLIST in cpp

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list, stack

So i am trying to create a c++ file which implements stack and all its functions(push,pop,getTop,etc). I want to use Template so that i can make this Stack class for multiple datatypes. I am using linked list to store the data. Here is some example of stack i have implemented using linked list.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>

class Node{
public:
      T data;
      Node *next;
      Node()
      {
            next = NULL;
      }
};

class Stack
{
      Node *top;
public:
      Stack();
      int isEmpty();
      int isFull();
      void push(T data);
      T pop();
      void display();
};

Stack :: Stack()
{
      top = NULL;
}

int Stack :: isEmpty()
{
      if(top == NULL)
      {
            return 1;
      }
      else
      {
            return 0;
      }
}

int Stack :: isFull()
{
      int temp;
      Node *t = new Node;

      if(t==NULL)
      {
            temp = 1;
      }
      else
      {
            temp = 0;
      }

      delete t;
      return temp;
}

void Stack :: push(T data)
{
      Node *n;

      if(isFull())
      {
            cout<<"\nStack overflow";
      }
      else
      {
            n = new Node;
            n->data = data;
            n->next = top;
            top = n;
      }

}

int Stack :: pop()
{
      Node *t;
      T temp;

      if(isEmpty())
      {
            return temp;
      }
      else
      {
            t = top;
            top = top->next;
            temp = t->data;
            delete t;
            return temp;
      }
}

void Stack :: display()
{
      Node *p = top;
      while(p != NULL)
      {
            cout<<"\n"<<p->data;
            p = p->next;
      }
}
```

So this is a preview of what i am trying to do, but i don't want to create different node and stack class for different data types. How can i achieve that using Templates. I tried it myself but i am getting lots of error and cant seem to understand why.
Thanks.

Comment: Provide the code that you have tried (even it's failed), so you will get better input.

Comment: What the heck is going on inside `isFull`?

Comment: Trying to figure out what your level of understanding is: Why do you have the line `template <class T>` before your definition of `Node`? Why do you *not* have that same line before your definition of `Stack`? (Beyond that discrepancy, the rest of your mistakes *might* come down to understanding the error messages you're getting. Are you sure you didn't want to ask about the first error your compiler reports?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest making the `Node` into an inner class of `Stack`. There's no need for users to be able to see it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<utility>

template<class T>
class Stack {
    struct Node {  // inner class
        T data;
        Node *next;
    };

    Node* top = nullptr;
    size_t m_size = 0;

public:
    Stack() = default;

    // rule of five - no copying, only moving allowed
    Stack(const Stack&) = delete;
    Stack(Stack&& rhs) noexcept :
        top(std::exchange(rhs.top, nullptr)), m_size(rhs.m_size) 
    {}
    Stack& operator=(const Stack&) = delete;
    Stack& operator=(Stack&& rhs) noexcept {
        std::swap(top, rhs.top);
        m_size = rhs.m_size;
        return *this;
    }
    ~Stack() {
        while(top) {
            delete std::exchange(top, top->next);
        }
    }

    bool empty() const { return m_size == 0; }
    size_t size() const { return m_size; }

    void push(const T& data) {
        top = new Node{data, top};
        ++m_size;
    }

    T pop() {
        T rv = std::move(top->data);
        delete std::exchange(top, top->next);
        --m_size;
        return rv;
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jxPbdfrYP)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement like bellow:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename Type>
class Node
{
public:
    Type data;
    Node<Type> *next;
};

template <typename Type>
class Stack
{
public:
    Node<Type> *top;
    void push(Type data);
    Type pop();
};


int main()
{

}
```

Comment: I don't think you'd template `Stack` over `typename Node` but rather `template<typename Type>` and then you would have a `Node<Type>` data member. That also means calling code doesn't have to be aware of the implementation detail of the `Node` class, you can just have a `Stack<int>` instead of a `Stack<Node<int>>`

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a stack with a linked list requires simply storing a linked list privately, and constraining it with the stack's interface. The constraining is the key. The template parameter is the type you are storing in your stack.

The simplest`*` way is to take the time implement a linked list *well*, so that you only have to worry about constraining it in your stack class and not writing a linked list to behave like a stack in your stack class. The principle at play here is called Separation of Concerns.

Here's a quick example using `std::list` for simplicity's sake:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Stack {
 public:
  Stack() = default;
  Stack(T val) : m_stack(val) {}
  void push(T val) { m_stack.push_front(val); }
  T& top() { return m_stack.front(); }
  void pop() {
    if (!m_stack.empty()) m_stack.pop_front();
  }
  bool empty() const { return m_stack.empty(); }

 private:
  std::list<T> m_stack{};
};
```

The `if` statement might not be necessary in the `pop()` function if you want the exception to be thrown in your stack.

Here's a `main()` that tests the stack:

```cpp
int main() {
  Stack<int> s1;
  for (int i = 1; i < 11; ++i) s1.push(i);
  while (!s1.empty()) {
    std::cout << s1.top() << ' ';
    s1.pop();
  }
  std::cout << '\n';

  Stack<char> s2('A');
  for (char l = 'B'; l != 'K'; ++l) s2.push(l);
  while (!s2.empty()) {
    std::cout << s2.top() << ' ';
    s2.pop();
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

My only includes are `<iostream>` and `<list>`. The output:

```
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
J I H G F E D C B
```

I am able to avoid a lot of unnecessary work like the Rule of 5 because `std::list` handles it all for me. So I am fine with compiler-provided copy and move constructors and the destructor.

`*` This is much easier said than done. I keep a simple linked list around for those specific questions, and it is still ~130 lines of code, and does not have all the functionality necessary to be properly constrained to behave like a stack like I demonstrate with `std::list`.

If you've written a linked list already, the stack should be very simple as successfully writing a linked list requires demonstrating an extremely wide range of C++ knowledge and programming principles.